# I am trying to find flight numbers and a booking reference

Tags: air-travel, delays

I am struggling to find flight numbers and a booking reference from Murcia Spain to Birmingham International from June 2011.  We were delayed over 5 hours in Murcia.  I have bank payment reference to BMI Derby and dates but thats it?

Comment: At least some credit cards show flight details, flight numbers and ticket numbers on the statement. American Express UK is one such. Any chance you paid with a helpful credit card company's card who could give you an old statement with that on?

Comment: A little bit interest that why you have to ind a booking 4 years ago?

Comment: BTW as i know the only direct flight between them is Ryanair 2155

Comment: @Him - likely looking for cash compensation under the EU delay rule.

Comment: Such a late claim

Comment: @Him A recent Court of Appeal ruling (Thomson v. Dawson) decided that the airlines' position that a two year limitation applied on such claims was unlawful (they held this view based on a misapprehension of the Montreal Convention---it doesn't apply to this kind of claim). Therefore the normal six year limitation period applies instead. The airlines did apply to the Supreme Court for permission to appeal the decision, but the Supreme Court declined to hear the appeal last Oct, and therefore the CoA ruling is now settled law in this matter. It suddenly makes such claims a lot cheaper to bring.

Answer (score 1):

If you made an online payment, then try to check your old emails. One should receive a confirmation mail if the booking was purchased online.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a frequent flyer account with that airline?  That would list flight numbers at least?

But otherwise, if there is no reference to the booking PNR or flights on your credit card statement and if you no longer have any emails with your confirmation or eTicket numbers in them, you are pretty much limited to asking the airline to research your old booking.

The airlines maintain booking records for a number of years, but older records are archived and the airline will charge a research fee to find it for you.  But as I am guessing you want this information to claim compensation for the delay from that same airline, I doubt they will be real keen to do your research.

Comment: If the airline still holds this information, (and to be honest, I doubt it), it would be counted as personal information. Therefore (assuming the company has a UK office) one could issue a Subject Access Request under the Data Protection Act to compel disclosure of the information. There could be a fee, but it is capped at (I think) about £10 by the statute. See http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1998/29/section/7?view=plain

Comment: Don't know all the PC rules in the EU, but with some US carriers you can access old bookings online back two years, then have to pay for research back beyond that.